# Vertical page animation transition in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to somehow get the Navigation Page transition to pop a page off vertically (say, slide off in the up direction) rather than the horizontal direction?

Comment: In my applications, the default transition is vertical sliding up, although I haven't set it in any way

Comment: https://github.com/bbl-Laobu/AnimatedTransitionNavPageDemo

Answer (score 2):

You can use Animation Navigation Page nuget available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XForms.Plugin.AnimationNavigationPage).

[image] [image]

Override the default Page Transitions for Xamarin.Forms when calling PushAsync and PopAsync.

Using the AnimationNavigationPage you can create a custom transition between different pages.

**Usage:**

1. Install nuget package for PCL/Net.Standard, IOS and Android projects. Then add the lines below.

   - **Android**: Add 'FormsControls.Droid.Main.Init()' into MainActivity.cs of your Xamarin Droid Project.
     [image]
   - **iOS**: Add 'FormsControls.Touch.Main.Init()' into AppDelegate.cs of your Xamarin.iOS Project.
     [image]
2. Declare AnimationNavigationPage:
   [image]
3. Create and Animation page

   - Firstly, make sure that the code behind inherits from AnimationPage:
     [image]
   - Next, use the 'controls:AnimationPage' tag instead of the 'ContentPage' tag as follows:
     [image]
   - Lastly, we must declare a tag in the page to specify which transition we would like to use:
     [image]

Please refer to this [link](https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage) to see full documentation.